# Bootstrap 3 - Press and hold delay for popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using bootstrap 3 for a project and I am looking for an option to have a link that on a single click redirects to another URL, but if the user holds the button down for 2-3 seconds a popover would appear. Like the mac dock - on one click it opens an app and on keeping the [mouse] button down you get a popover with separate options.

All suggestions highly appreciated..

Thank you

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with bootstrap.

Comment: except that I use bootstrap popovers...

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for 2-3 seconds and call bootstrap's popover.
Try this DEMO:  http://jsbin.com/bohibeco/8/edit